# Multivariable Calculus: Intersection of surface and planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, plane-curves

I have this math problem:

> Let $S$ be the surface that consists of all points $(x,y,z)$ that
>   satisfy the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$.
>
> 1) What are the intersections of $S$ with horizontal planes $z=h$?
>
> 2) What is the intersection of $S$ with the $yz$-plane $x=0$?
>
> 3) Describe $S$.
>
> 4) Describe the space curve $C$ defined by
>   $r(t)=tcost(t)i+tsin(t)j+tk$ and verify that $C$ lies on S.

I have no idea where to start. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\phi_{+}: \mathbb{R}^2\to S$, defined by $$\phi_{+}(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}),$$
is a local map of $S$, as well as $\phi_{-}: \mathbb{R}^2\to S$, defined by $$\phi_{-}(x,y)=(x,y,-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).$$

1) The intersection of $S$ and the horizontal plane $z=h$ is a circle of radius $h$.

2) You can to think like the item 1), but you go to found two lines.

3) $S$ is described by your local maps.

4) You can to see that $C$ is a spiral curve.

Errata: We have a problem when $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, because we don't' have the tangent plane in this point. So, $S-\{(0,0,0)\}$ is a smooth surface, non-connected.